# Implement search for android grid view

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-search

I have gridview in my android app which displays images and text so i want to add searchview in gridview so that when i type something in searchview i should be able to see matching gridview items.i dont know how to implement my search view for array linked to that grid.
Thanks in advance

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override



// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder mVHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
        mVHolder=new ViewHolder();



        mVHolder.mTextView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(mVHolder);

    } else {
        mVHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    mVHolder.mTextView.setText(mThumbIds[position]);

    return convertView;}




// array of strings

private String[] mThumbIds = {......};
 }

class ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextView;

}
```

Comment: Use a recylerview with a girdlayout manager instead. There are plenty of tutorials out there for implementing a search on a recyclerview. Also recyclerview will prevent a lot of issues you will face in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/zpwrsg/add-search-function-to-list-view-in-android) on how to provide search functionality to ListViews.

You have to create a SearchView

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
```

Implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and add its unimplented methods which are

```
@Override

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

    return true;
}
```

Implement Filterable to your BaseAdapter.
You would have to create a arraylist for your Filtered data.